# How do I parse text from email body using a Rails3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, email

I need to get the name and email address from a forwarded email where there is a line like this in the body:

```
From: john smith <sales@domain.com>
```

What is the best way to do this? Is there a good library/gem I should use?

Also this line will vary from which email client it's sent from and also what language, so I need a more robust way than just matching just this string.

Also some clients do not include the name but just the email address on this line so I need to be able to handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require 'mail'  # only needed for non-Rails
m = Mail.new( "any RFC-conforming email including headers" )
puts m[:from].display_names.first
puts m[:from].addresses.first
```

The `Mail` object is automatically included in Rails projects that use `ActionMailer` - but you'll need to add it to your `Gemfile` if you're not using `ActionMailer`

#### Update

I didn't read the OP's question properly - they want to get an email address from the body of a forwarded mail.  I'd just use some regex:

```
name, email = m.body.match( /^\s*From:\s*(.*)\s+<(.*)>$/)[1,2]
```

NB: this assumes a fair amount about the structure of the email - an HTML-only email can easily thwart this regex.

Comment: This is the best way; There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Absolutely we tried a few options to recommend CloudMailin users. Mail can be a very complex thing to work with especially when they're malformed but the mail gem is awesome

Comment: @Jason King      i am not try to get the from address from the headers, as this will be the person who forwarded the email to my

Comment: app,  but i want to get the person who sent it to the person who forwarded it to my app ?